# Reset animation Jquery when modal closes

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

My cart icon is in the middle. But how do i reset the position again. So when i close the Modal i want it to be in the middle again. `$("#addedToCartModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function () {`

```
$(document).ready ( function () {
$("#addedToCartModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function(){
      $('.modal-backdrop').css('opacity', '.91');

                setTimeout(function () {
                function animate() {
                    $(".cart-after-item-added").animate({"margin-left":"105%"}, 2000, 'linear',function(){
                            $('.cart-after-item-added').css({"margin-left":"-133%"});
                            $(".cart-after-item-added").animate({"margin-left":"50%"}, 4000, 'linear',function(){
                            animate();
                    });
              });
            }
                animate();
                }, 250);
        });
        $("#addedToCartModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
// ANIMATION STOPS BUT HOW TO RESET?
    $('#addedToCartModal').stop();
});
});
```

Comment: The easiest way to do this is via CSS. You have two states: 'normal' and 'active.' on the 'shown.bs.modal' event, you can just target the element and add the class to it (which you animate via CSS keyframes. When it's done, you just remove the class from the element.

Comment: @JoelHager So your saying, animate with CSS keyframes no with jQuery animate? And then just remove class after?

Comment: @JoelHager I meant "not with jQuery Animate?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT to give your particular use-case***

```
$(document).ready ( function () {

$("#addedToCartModal").on("shown.bs.modal", setActive(true) );
    $("#addedToCartModal").on('hide.bs.modal', setActive(false) );
function setActive(show) {
    (show == true) ? $('#addedToCartModal').addClass("active") : $('#addedToCartModal').removeClass("active);
}
```

});

Yes. You store the states with css classes, where the default state is the class of the actual item, and the modified state is a class that's added/removed on some event (in my fiddle, it's a click). Then with CSS you can animate between the two. The fiddle below will illustrate my meaning. Let me know if I can be more specific. :)

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("toggle");
var sample = document.getElementById("sample");

function toggle() {
  (sample.classList.contains("active")) ? sample.classList.remove("active") : sample.classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
.sample {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #999999;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.sample.active {
  background-color: #333333;
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="sample" class="sample"></div>
</div>
<button id="toggle" onClick="toggle()">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer i will try this tomorrow. Its almost 4:30AM here. Will let you know, thanks for your time.

Comment: all you have to do is add the CSS properties to an `active` class or whatever name you have, and then take the `function() {}` part of the state change. I'll add the updated js to fit your use-case.

Comment: How wcan i reproduce the same animation effect. I dont understand the first block of your code. Cant see results with that first block of code

Comment: Like, the cart needs to go to the right behind overflow:hidden. Then i move it with css to the left again and let it show the cart and it will ride again, that goes in a loop.

Comment: How willl it go back to the beginning with toggle if i also use CSS for it going from right to the left situation at the beginning (see my jquery code). AND i dont like javascript by the way, i use Jquery

Comment: There is alot of confusion while i am busy with this. Like i can use the TransformX to the right. I dont need the toggle button. 

I know made the code that if i open the modal the animation will start and if i close the modal the toggle happens so then it will reset again. 

But how will i make the next step on transformation with this cart. The cart goes to the right now. But how will it go back to square 1 and go from left to right again without breaking the toggle effect(that it will go back to original place).

Comment: Can you post the html/css/js here in a snippet for me to work with?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and time. Sorry that i was so late things went wrong for recreating it but it WORKED. See https://jsfiddle.net/6qhu0kmc/  . As you can see when you press the button the cart goes to the right and vanishes `overflow:hidden`. The next step i want it to be is like my animate CSS code `$('.cart-after-item-added').css({"margin-left":"-133%"});` Then the cart will move behind the `overflow:hidden` and then the cart should go from left to right again until the cart is hidden again. I am excited on how this is gonna be solved. I appreciate it.

Comment: Djeezz, can you see the JSfiddle output? It doesn't work inside JSFIDDLE dont know why. I am having the same issue alot these last day's. But you could copy everything inside a HTML file. That should work

Comment: Let me know because i am waiting on your answer. I am gonna sleep now. Thanks for your time

Comment: Is this not what you were intending? I changed some things. Let me know if that fixes it for you. https://jsfiddle.net/jrhager84/4ny2ruv8/5/

Comment: No, the cart goes only to the right. I want it in a loop. So the cart need to go right then it will hide. After that put the cart at beginning  (not the middle) and go from left to right again. The cart just needs to go from left to right

Comment: Ah. Then you want an animation. I'll set it up

Comment: This is what you're looking for then. https://jsfiddle.net/jrhager84/4ny2ruv8/7/

Comment: Wauw thanks for this and your time. But i want it to start from the middle to the right and go in a loop from left beginning to right end. Is that possible? I am trying to do that now

Comment: The animation with jQuery in my question is the same as i describe in my previous comment. Is this possible? Let me know

Comment: Want it exactlyl like this if it is possible. `$(".cart-after-item-added").animate({"margin-left":"105%"}, 2000, 'linear',function(){
                            $('.cart-after-item-added').css({"margin-left":"-133%"});
                            $(".cart-after-item-added").animate({"margin-left":"50%"}, 4000, 'linear',function(){` See my question

Comment: Hello how are you , did you see my comments?

Comment: Yes. I'm at my computer now. I'll give something a go. :)

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/jrhager84/4ny2ruv8/15/

Comment: Wooow i thought it couldn't be possible honestly. But YOU DID IT. I am smiling right now hahaha. Perfect. If i had a job i would've give you like a little bit of money. That's how happy i am with this. Thank you so so so much and sorry for haunting you for this haha. Thanks man, stay safe and have a nice evening. Greetings from Amsterdam

Comment: Not necessary at all. Glad to be of help. To give you a bit of insight on how I did this: I started the animation at translateX(0). Then I went to 50% to 300%, then for 1% I made it invisible and moved it to -300%. Then finished the animation from -300% to 0 and it loops. So technically, it's going from mid to right, turning invisible, resetting left, and becoming visible again and looping back. It's a bit hacky, but it's such a minor thing it's totally what we have to do with CSS. hahaha